# ParametricPlot3D line not smooth

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

Multivariate parameters appear to present a jagged appearance of integrands (using default Runge-Kutta ODE integration intervals?) in ParametricPlot3D plotting on a single argument.

Higher Mesh.. ing to 200  improves sectors' jagging (large step secants appearing instead of tangent) somewhat, but still color from PlotStyle for lines does not come through, e.g., like in case of the straight computed helical lines shown. How to get PlotStyle line colors with  smoother lines?

```
thmax=6Pi ;
EQU={SI'[th]==Sin[PH[th]],SI[0]==.123,
PH'[th]==Cos[th],PH[0]==-1.234,
Z'[th]==2 Cos[PH[th]]Cos[SI[th]],
R'[th]==3 Sin[PH[th]] Cos[SI[th]],
R[0]==1.321,Z[0]==0.};
NDSolve[EQU,{SI,PH,R,Z},
  {th,0,thmax}];
  {ph[u_],si[u_],
  r[u_],z[u_]}={PH[u],
  SI[u],R[u],Z[u]}/.First[%];
ParametricPlot[{z[th],r[th]},{th,0,thmax},
   AspectRatio->Automatic,PlotLabel->MERIDIAN_,PlotStyle->{Thick,Magenta}]
ParametricPlot3D[{r[th] Cos[th+t],z[th],r[th] Sin[th+t]},{t,0,2 Pi},    
   {th,0,thmax},PlotLabel->SURFACE_]
SpC1=ParametricPlot3D[{r[th] Cos[th],z[th],r[th] Sin[th]},{t,0,2 Pi},
   {th,0,thmax},PlotStyle->{Thick,Magenta},PlotLabel->SPACE_CURVE,Mesh->20];
SpC2=ParametricPlot3D[{2 Sin[th],th,1.8 Cos[th]},{th,0,thmax/3},
   PlotLabel->HELIX_,PlotStyle->{Thick,Magenta}];
Show[SpC1,SpC2]
```

Comment: Please format your code by selecting it and pressing the code button (`{}`) in the toolbar. Right now it is difficult to read.

Comment: Thanks Rahulji, will format it hereafter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove `{t, 0, 2 Pi}` from your `SpC1` to get a 3D parametrized line

```
SpC1b = ParametricPlot3D[{r[th] Cos[th], z[th], r[th] Sin[th]}, {th, 0, thmax},
           PlotStyle -> {Thick, Magenta}, PlotLabel -> "SPACE_CURVE"];
Show[SpC1b, SpC2]
```

[image]

Or, to get fancier,

```
Show[SpC1b /. {Magenta -> Orange, Line -> (Tube[#, .1] &)},
 SpC2 /. Line -> (Tube[#, .1] &), Background -> Black, Boxed -> False, Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

[image]

and, increasing `thmax` to `36 Pi`,

[image]

**Note:** As is, your code for `SpC1`produces a 3D *surface* parametrized by `t` and `th`. That is,  it produces polygons. So, you can change the setting for `PlotStyle` in your code to `PlotStyle -> EdgeForm[{Thick, Magenta}]` to make the polygons "look like" a `Magenta`-colored line. However, this approach is both unnecessary and slow because of the number of polygons produced: In your original version with `Mesh->20` it produces

```
Total@Cases[SpC1[[1]], Polygon[x_] :> Length[x], {0, Infinity}]
(* 10 471 *)
```

of them. Changing to  `Mesh->200` produces `90 643` polygons; and using the options settings `Mesh -> 100, PlotPoints -> 200, MaxRecursion -> 1` produces `485 208` tiny polygons. Since each polygon is small, together they appear as a `Line`.

Comment: I like the like the fancy Part, +1.

Answer (score 2):

I´m not quite sure whether I understood your problem right, but I increased the Mesh, set the PlotPoints higher (I just choose a higher number) and MaxRecursion to 1, i.e.:

```
SpC1 = ParametricPlot3D[{r[th] Cos[th], z[th], r[th] Sin[th]}, {t, 0, 
   2 Pi}, {th, 0, thmax}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Magenta}, 
  PlotLabel -> SPACE_CURVE, Mesh -> 100, PlotPoints -> 200, 
  MaxRecursion -> 1]
```

and

```
SpC2 = ParametricPlot3D[{2 Sin[th], th, 1.8 Cos[th]}, {th, 0, 
   thmax/3}, PlotLabel -> HELIX_, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Magenta}, 
  PlotPoints -> 200, MaxRecursion -> 1]
```

the result was than quite different

[image: new picture]